# PySpark: How do I send the RDD to a map function with dataFrame input in spark

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to used RDD in pyspark. Starting with the simple example estimating  the pi where:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

appName = "tutApp"
master = "local"
NUM_SAMPLE = 100
NUM_PARALLIZE = xrange(0, NUM_SAMPLE)

import random
def sample(p):
    x, y = random.random(), random.random()
    return 1 if x*x + y*y < 1 else 0

count = sc.parallelize(NUM_PARALLIZE).map(sample).reduce(lambda a, b: a+b)
t = (4.0 * count/NUM_SAMPLE)
print "----- Pi is roughly %", t
```

I want to use the same approach, where the map function in my case (APR),  getting input, which is the data frame instead of x,y in the sample function. I am using pandas and it seems that spark has difficulty for distributing tasks by map function in my case.

```
sc.parallelize(PrepAPR(0,1)).count()
```

gives me the number of nodes and this part is working.

PrepAPR is a class where I am returning the tuple in a lazy way that can be used as an input for the map function. Having the function sample, I want to do transformation as

```
.map(lambda t: APR (t)) and t is a tuple of (df,a,b,c).
```

I am getting this error

```
SystemError: error return without exception set.
```

I appreciate if some one answer my question.

"""APR SPark"""

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

class PrepAPR:
    def __init__(self, low, high):
        self.current = low
        self.high = high

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def prep_data_for_turbine(self):
        turbines=all_turbines[self.current:self.current+1]
        return turbines

    def next(self): # Python 3: def __next__(self)
        if self.current > self.high:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
#             tpl =  self.current 
            tpl = self.prep_data_for_turbine()
            self.current += 1
            return tpl
def sami(t):
    model= MODEL
    df= dFrames["Data"]
    features=FEATURES
    turbines=all_turbines[t:t+1]
    return actual_pred_resid (df, model, features, turbines)


# print sc.parallelize(PrepAPR(0,1)).count()
APR_df = sc.parallelize([1,2]).map(lambda t: sami(t)).count()
#print APR_df.collect()
```

Comment: Cannot you paste the actual code here?

Comment: @ShuaiYuan I already added my code. You can treat the model, data, and features as a parameter.

Comment: Well... unfortunately I cannot make sense of your code at all, especially `sami` and things after it. Let's hope somebody could.